# Limit of script tags during development

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

How many `<script src="scripts/...js"></script>` can an index.html file handle?

In production, they are all combined but can I have hundreds in development or it will start to be very slow?

I am building a very large application and I suspect there will be +300 files. Will that work just by having them all listed in index.html during development?

I am asking to determine how many controllers/services I should place in each file during development.

Please advise.

Comment: you could let requirejs manage this for you.

Comment: Why you don't go for server side bundling?

Comment: There are no browser limits that will be hit by this.. so yes, you *could* do that. However, I recommend better automation of the tooling.

Comment: This is probably not something you should spend time worrying about. You're trying to solve a problem you don't have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the "development" site on my local machine, I've never run into that problem, but I've never really tested it beyond a hundred or so. I suppose if you developed on a remote host you would.

Answer (score 2):

Each script file you list will require a connection from your browser to your server to retrieve the file.  This can be very slow, especially with "hundreds" of includes.  After the first visit, your browser should cache the resource files and hopefully serve them from cache on subsequent page loads (unless your server is set to expire them relatively quickly).  I have no information on hard limits for includes, but I am pretty sure each browser would handle it a little bit different.  Regardless, you should limit your includes as much as possible.

Comment: For *development* there is little concern waiting a few extra milliseconds as it's likely the server is "local". That isn't to say that it isn't messy or can't be improved.

Comment: @user2864740 Anything worth doing is worth doing right.